# Is there a way to set miracast over infrastructure mode for p2p interface

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wireless, wpa-supplicant, wifi-direct

Hi all I just wanted to know is it possible to enable a p2p-dev-wlan0(p2p interface) for miracast over infrastructure mode. I think from wpa_cli we can set ap_vendor_elements to append the beacon and probe response frames, but I'm not sure will it work with with the capability of p2p device interface. 
Any help would be appreciated.

I have a USB wifi adapter of rtl8812au chip set.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Use bridge,

if Miracast streams from 192.168.0.2
and Router address is 192.168.0.1

Local subnet is 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0

> openvpn --mktun --dev tap0
>
> brctl addbr br0
>
> brctl addif br0 eth0
>
> brctl addif br0 tap0
>
> ifconfig tap0 0.0.0.0 promisc up
>
> ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 promisc up
>
> ifconfig br0 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 192.168.255.255
>
> route add default gw 192.168.0.1 br0

If you must use Layer 3 and mask illegal kind of stuff,
do the iptables correctly.

accept miracastaddress/4 udp from anywhere to anywhere

also,

accept igmp from anywhere to anywhere